# PHP - Show box for each product

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

I'm trying to display one of these boxes : ([Image here](https://gyazo.com/a1bf7160454fb9b890126de6d2b2a389)) for every product. But when I add another product in the database, it doesn't seem to add another on view for my products page. [Here](https://gyazo.com/928f5ef5d20b95f5ffbc6d1cf29ccaf7) you see my database, but only one image on my products page. The page looks as same as the first image posted above. If anyone knows why my products aren't showing for each product, only the first one, then please let me know. ***I know my code is not secure, not neat. I will do that after I'm done getting this to work so don't judge me on that. Only the issue I asked. Thanks.***

**My PHP code is all in this one function which I call in my div containers :**

```
function grabProducts($con) {

    ?>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="col-md-12" id="please_wait">
        <div class="panel panel-warning">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title"><i>Loading, Please Wait...</i></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#please_wait').fadeOut(7000);
        $('#content_purchase').hide(0).delay(5000).fadeIn("slow");
    });
    </script>
    <?php

    $users = $this->grabUserInfos($con);
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $username = $user[1];
        $email = $user[3];
    }

    $site_config = new site_config();
    $member_config = new member_config();

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM products");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $site_callback = $site_config->grabSiteSettings_manual($con, 'site_url').'/pizza/includes/checkout.php';
    $site_return_success = $site_config->grabSiteSettings_manual($con, 'site_url').'/pizza/products.php?status=complete';
    $site_return_canceled = $site_config->grabSiteSettings_manual($con, 'site_url').'/pizza/products.php?status=canceled';

    // See if there are any products in the database
    if ($count > 0) {

        // While loop for each product element
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $picture = $row['picture_location'];
            $price = $row['price'];
            $stock_monitering = $row['stock_monitering'];
            //$stock = $row['stock'];

            // Count the number links in each product
            $product_count = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ebook WHERE used_status = '0'");
            $row_product_count = mysqli_fetch_row($product_count);
            $count_product_stock = $row_product_count[0];
            $stock = $count_product_stock;

            $new_stock = $stock - 1;

            $getValidatedCheck_ = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT txn_id, hasValidated, item_name, amount, currency, payment_date FROM payment_logs WHERE userId = '$username' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

            // Count the number of payment_logs that correspond to the logged in user
            $payment_log_count = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM payment_logs WHERE userId = '$username'");
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($payment_log_count);
            $count_payment_logs = $row[0];

            $now = strtotime("-10 minutes");

            // If there are no transactions for that user show the products like normal
            if($count_payment_logs <= 0) {
                // If there is not enough stock, show out of stock
                if($stock <= 0) {
                    $display = "out_of_stock";
                } else if($stock > 0) {
                    $display = "show_products";
                }
            } else if($count_payment_logs >= 1) {

                // While loop for our successful payment_logs for each user
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getValidatedCheck_)) {                        
                    $txn_id = $row['txn_id'];
                    $validated_check = $row['hasValidated'];    
                    $item_name = $row['item_name'];
                    $item_price = $row['amount'];   
                    $item_currency = $row['currency'];
                    $payment_date = $row['payment_date'];

                    // If they've not already seen the success message, show them it now and update their hasValidated from 0 to 1 so they don't see it again
                    if ($validated_check == '0') {
                        // If stock monitering is on, update our stock to 1 less than we had before the purchase
                        if($stock_monitering == '1') {
                            mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE products SET stock = '$new_stock' WHERE name = '$name'");
                        }
                        $product_count = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE ebook SET used_status = '1', assigned_to = '$username',  transaction_id = '$txn_id' WHERE used_status = '0'");
                        $display = "show_success";
                    } else {
                        if($stock <= 0) {
                            $display = "out_of_stock";
                        } else if($stock > 0) {
                            $display = "show_products";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    switch($display) {
        case "show_products":
            ?>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="content_purchase" style="display: none;">
                <div class="panel panel-danger">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Price: <i>$<?php echo $price; ?></i>
                            <div class="fRight" style="float: right;"><i><?php echo $name; ?></i> Stock
                                (<?php echo $stock; ?>)
                            </div>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <center>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <img src="<?php echo $picture; ?>"
                                 style="width: 85%; height: 100px; margin: 15px 0px 15px 0px; border-radius: 5px; border: 2px solid #ED4949;">
                            <form name="paypal_form" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $site_config->grabSiteSettings_manual($con, 'paypal_address'); ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $price; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
                                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                                <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="username=<?php echo $username; ?>&product= <?php echo $name; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo $site_callback; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $site_return_success; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo $site_return_canceled; ?>">

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"
                                        style="vertical-align : bottom; margin-bottom: 15px; display: block; width: 85%;">
                                    <i class="fa fa-paypal"></i>aypal
                                </button>
                                <form>
                        </div>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
            ';
        break;
        case "show_success":
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-12" id="content_purchase" style="display: none;">
            <div class="panel panel-success">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"><i>PAYMENT SUCCESS!</i></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>You've successfully purchased <i><?php echo $item_name; ?></i> for <i><?php echo $item_price; ?> <i><?php echo $item_currency; ?></i>. We have emailed you your receipt to <?php echo $email; ?>. You can click <a href="myFiles.php" style="color: white;">here</a> to download your purchased files.<br>Click <a href="<?php echo $url_path; ?>" style="color: white;">here</a> to purchase again.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE payment_logs SET hasValidated = '1' WHERE userId = '$username' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
        break;
        case "no_products":
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-12" id="content_purchase" style="display: none;">
            <div class="panel panel-danger">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"><i>Currently No Products For Sale</i></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>There are currently no products up for sale.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        break;
        case "out_of_stock":
        ?>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="content_purchase" style="display: none;">
                <div class="panel panel-danger">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Price: <i>$<?php echo $price; ?></i>
                            <div class="fRight" style="float: right;"><i><?php echo $name; ?></i> Stock
                                (<?php echo $stock; ?>)
                            </div>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <center>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <img src="<?php echo $picture; ?>"
                                 style="width: 85%; height: 100px; margin: 15px 0px 15px 0px; border-radius: 5px; border: 2px solid #ED4949;">
                            <p style="margin: 0px 15px 0px 15px;"><i><?php echo $name; ?></i> is currently out of stock. Please come back later and try again.</p>
                        </div>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        break;
    }
    }
    } else {
        $display = 'no_products';
    }
 }
```

Comment: you are forgetting starting tag or doing a syntax mistake here  '; break; case "show_success": ?>
may be this is reason why it is not showing more than 1 product.

Comment: @MahmoodSanjrani Oh yes, thank you but this has not fixed it.

Comment: have to tried to print something in while loop. may be loop isn't working as you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You should also loop your UI box so that you can have the same number of the product in the database and the box printed.

```
$sql = "Select * from product";
foreach('fetch all product from DB'){
?>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="content_purchase" style="display: none;">
        <div class="panel panel-danger">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Price: <i>$<?php echo $price; ?></i>
                    <div class="fRight" style="float: right;"><i><?php echo $name; ?></i> Stock
                        (<?php echo $stock; ?>)
                    </div>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <center>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <img src="<?php echo $picture; ?>"
                             style="width: 85%; height: 100px; margin: 15px 0px; border-radius: 5px; border: 2px solid #ED4949;">
                    <form name="paypal_form" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $site_config->grabSiteSettings_manual($con, 'paypal_address'); ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $price; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
                        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                        <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="username=<?php echo $username; ?>&product= <?php echo $name; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo $site_callback; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $site_return_success; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo $site_return_canceled; ?>">

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"
                                    style="vertical-align : bottom; margin-bottom: 15px; display: block; width: 85%;">
                            <i class="fa fa-paypal"></i>aypal
                        </button>
                    <form>
                </div>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
} //end loop
```

sorry I forgot the syntax. :D but that's the logic.

Comment: Okay thank you but could you explain / help me out with what goes in the foreach syntax ?

Comment: native PHP for now. It won't let me put a foreach inside my case function. It shows me the error `syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE), expecting case (T_CASE) or default (T_DEFAULT) or '}'`

Comment: as far as I remember this will do. :) just search some example. I might wrong. :)                                                                                                 $result = mysql_query("select * from mytable");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo $row->user_id;
    echo $row->fullname;
}

Comment: and make sure the for loop is inside the php tag.

Comment: can you help me with the foreach. The syntax you posted isn't accurate.